# two Virtual host not working on debian 7 server

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, debian-7.6.0

the first one already working great with this virtual host conf file et-project and target "et-project.net" domain.

```
<VirtualHost et-project.net:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@et-project.net
    ServerName  et-project.net
    ServerAlias www.et-project.net

    # Les documents du site (Souvent /var/www/monsite ou /home/monsite)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/et-project.net

    # Les options du site (comme dans un .htaccess)
    <Directory /var/www/et-project.net/>
        # On autorise tous le monde a voir le site
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Les logs (historiques des IPs et des fichiers envoyés)
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/et-project.net-error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/et-project.net-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

This my second subdomain conf file dev.et-project.net who need to target on dev.et-project.net:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@et-project.net
    ServerName  dev.et-project.net

    # Les documents du site (Souvent /var/www/monsite ou /home/monsite)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev.et-project.net

    # Les options du site (comme dans un .htaccess)
    <Directory "/var/www/dev.et-project.net/">
        # On autorise tous le monde a voir le site
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # Les logs (historiques des IPs et des fichiers envoyés)
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dev.et-project.net-error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/dev.et-project.net-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

i was already create dev.et-project.net folder in /var/www and add chmod 755 -r on him

My problem is this one : when i tape dev.et-project.net i already be redirect on et-project.net ... but when i tape my_ip_server/dev.et-project.net i see my dev subdomain directory.

- i was already add my_ip_server dev.et-project.net into my hosts file.
- i was already activate my vhost conf with a2ensite command and restart apache2 on my debian server.

so if you have some advise or know why my dev.et-project.net subdomain don't work with apache2 vhost , let me know plz.

regard

Comment: Maybe change <VirtualHost *:80> to <VirtualHost dev.et-project.net:80> ? dev.et-project.net have really domain name et-project.net and you say to Apache to listen , for  dev.et-project.net , on all address , i think the server can't understand. Another check:  execute  ls -l /etc/apache2/site-enabled/ and check in all vhosts files if your are a DocumentRoot conflict (i.e 00-default.conf etc...) and verify you are not declared anywhere <VirtualHost *:80> using joker but domain name.

Comment: @f14284 i check and modify my conf files. so a2dissite 00-default vhost, change <VirtualHost *:80> to <VirtualHost dev.et-project.net:80> and see any changes ... don't really understand why only my domain name vhost working and my subdomain don't ...

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong part of your second vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  dev.et-project.net
```

must be:

```
<VirtualHost dev.et-project.net:80>
    ServerName  dev.et-project.net
```

And the first

```
<VirtualHost et-project.net:80>
    ServerName  et-project.net
    ServerAlias www.et-project.net
```

In the /etc/hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   et-project.net www.et-project.net dev.et-project.net
```

And then

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

And clean your webbrowser cache. (close and reopen is a good solution)

I have try, on a fresh install, putting the wildcard '*' ,same as you, and i have the **same error**.

```
<VirtualHost dev.et-project.net:80>
```

is require for telling apache2 to find correct root folder of host.

I you see sudirectory : http://127.0.0.1/dev.example.com then you have another vhost listenning with documentroot /var/www (see into /etc/apache2/apache2.conf) but is not a problem, your problem is: you use wildcard. You can confirm that: you use -Index into your vhost directory configuration .But apache2 list your subdirectory http://127.0.0.1/dev.example.com then your vhost is not the current loaded vhost because this option disallow index listing. Sorry for my english.

**EDIT**: for this problem in particular , the CNAME DNS record was missing.

Comment: can you check my last answer plz, regard @f14284

Answer (score 0):

@f14284

i was change all, but nothing working yet. only et-project.net working.

if you are french, we will maybe continue on skype or other way for solved my problem ... are you ok for that ?

at the moment, that is my conf files vhosts and host.

dev.et-project

```
<VirtualHost dev.et-project.net:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@et-project.net
    ServerName  dev.et-project.net

    # Les documents du site (Souvent /var/www/monsite ou /home/monsite)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dev.et-project.net

    # Les options du site (comme dans un .htaccess)
    <Directory "/var/www/dev.et-project.net/">
        # On autorise tous le monde a voir le site
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Les logs (historiques des IPs et des fichiers envoyés)
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/dev.et-project.net-error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/dev.et-project.net-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

here my et-project

```
<VirtualHost et-project.net:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@et-project.net
    ServerName  et-project.net
    ServerAlias www.et-project.net

    # Les documents du site (Souvent /var/www/monsite ou /home/monsite)
    DocumentRoot /var/www/et-project.net

    # Les options du site (comme dans un .htaccess)
    <Directory /var/www/et-project.net/>
        # On autorise tous le monde a voir le site
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    # Les logs (historiques des IPs et des fichiers envoyés)
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/et-project.net-error_log
    TransferLog /var/log/apache2/et-project.net-access_log
</VirtualHost>
```

and my dedicate server hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost et-project.net www.et-project.net dev.et-project.net
#127.0.1.1      sd-66352.dedibox.fr project
62.210.127.101  et-project.net project
62.210.127.101  et-project.net www.et-project.net dev.et-project.net
```

all my config is here now and it's so sad for me to don't solved this problem since one week.

regard

Comment: I have try to create a room but : Users must have at least 20 reputation to talk

Comment: i have updown your questions... you have more 20 reputation... go to the chat, search for room 'Apache 2 problem', normally for server config etc.. it's on serverfault not really stack ...but..

Comment: @f14284 no have 20 reputation, only 8 , maybe we can go discord if you can ?

Comment: you have 23 ... please refresh the page , you must go to : https://chat.stackoverflow.com and after that i can add you

Comment: i am on him, i wait you

Comment: can you find 'Apache 2 problem' room : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167982/apache-2-problem

Comment: Yes but on stackover i have 23 reputation, but on chat thez don't update yet my reputation only 8 ...

Comment: yes i see that... i have not another chat system on my computer sorry

Comment: @f14284 Really  strange, don't understand chat reputation isn't update yet ^^ ... 
can you give me on email for invite you on slack ; i have create work group for chat easily

Comment: no i have not an email adress, i use only stackoverflow, servfault and stackexchange.

Comment: Yes but reputation bug on chat so how can we speak ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167985/discussion-between-f14284-and-elderyn).

Comment: click on : Let us continue this discussion in chat, here